# What is the meaning and structure of this sentence which has commma?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

In the sentence below:

> The North Bridge and South Bridge together form the computer’s chipset**,** secondary only to the processor in determining the performance and capabilities of a PC.

The first part does make sense.

> The North Bridge and South Bridge together form the computer’s chipset

But after the "comma",

> secondary only to the processor in determining the performance and capabilities of a PC

What is this structure? What is the verb for this? What does "secondary to" mean?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> second(ary) only to

means:

> the first, except

---

> Jane is second only to Cathy.

Only Cathy is "ahead" of Jane, and nobody else.

---

> the chipset is secondary only to the processor

Only the processor is more important than the chipset.

---

Special case:

> He is second to **none**.

he is the first after (nobody) - therefore he is actually the first.